# Odd behaviour of clickable <div> on Touch?

Tags: html, css, angular

So first of all, thank you for reading and helping me out.
I've spent the last 4 hours on the web searching for a solution for my strange problem.

**Problem**

I create a `<div>` with `(click)` action. Style it with CSS classes, `:hover`, `:active` and `:focus`. When I click it with mouse, everything is good. But when I touch it with a touchscreen, a oddly gray overlay appears (*see the linked GIFs*)!!

[Behaviour when mouse-clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lvKH.gif)

[Behaviour when touched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaNNt.gif)

Here is a snippet like my code:

```css
#btn-container {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
  color: black;
}

#btn-container:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 200,200,200 );
}

#btn-container:active {
  background-color: rgb( 150,150,150 );
  transition: 0s;
}

#btn-container:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


.standard-btn {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}


html {
  /* Prevent user to select text */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer, Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non prefixed version: Chrome, Opera */
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-container" class="standard-btn">Touch me</div>
```

PS: I'm developing in Angular. I've tested this strange behaviour on Chrome for Android, Safari on iOS, Chrome, Edge, IE on Windows.
The oddity is that, for example, on JSFiddle ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/jL9x4hwz/)) or here on StackOverflow this doesn't happen. And it doesn't happen also on another Angular app of mine.... and I wasn't able to find out WHY, CSS/HTML/JS are *exactly* the same between the two apps. That's crazy.

Comment: Hi, did you try to set `outline: none;` on the button element?

Comment: Yes tried, no results

Comment: Don't use `<div>`s when you need a `<button>`. Please. Accessibility matters.

Comment: This is obvious. But the goal of the site is to solve this problem, aside from the use case. And my case is an Angular app for my personal use and I don't care for Aria labels and accessibility. However, I think the same behaviour happens also with `<button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved. I'll post here the solution for future reference.

I just needed to add the property `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent` on the main button class. As it is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) described, this is not a standard property. But it worked!

Referencing to the code snippet from the question, I've modified the `#btn-container` class, in this way:

```
#btn-container {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
  color: black;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* <-- this is new */
}
```